# How can create a newenvironement for exercises Solutions

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, book-design, exercises

I am trying to create a book with exercises and solutions, I would like to insert each exercise in tcolorbox, I don't want to repeat each time this command

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,title=exercice 1 ,attach boxed title to top center=
    {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=cyan}]
```

to create a exercice, is there any other method to create a New environement without repeating in each time this command.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,title=exercice 1 ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=cyan}]
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item Résoudre les équations suivantes:
   \begin{eqnarray}
    \nonumber 4x=16\hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} (2x-7)(x+9)=0
   \end{eqnarray}
\item Résoudre les inéquations suivantes:
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
 2x\le 22 \hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} -5x\le 6
\end{eqnarray}
\item On considère le système suivant: 
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber (E):\left\{
 \begin{array}{lll}
  3x-y=6\\ x+2y=16
 \end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
est ce qu le paire $(5;9)$ est une solution pour $(E)$
\item résoudre $(E)$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,title=exercice 2 ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=cyan}]
Le tableau suivant, donne les quantités d'oranges récoltées dans un champ par le nombre d'ouvriers pendant chaque journée:
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  la quantité d'oranges (Kg) & 100 & 120 & 140 & 160 & 200 \\\hline
  l'effectif (nombre d'ouvriers) & 20 & 30 & 10 & 25 & 15\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\item donner le nombre total des ouvriers recensés. \item quel est le mode de cette série statistique.
Calculer la moyenne arithmétique de cette série statistique.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,title=exercice 1 ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=cyan}]
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item Résoudre les équations suivantes:
   \begin{eqnarray}
    \nonumber 4x=16\hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} (2x-7)(x+9)=0
   \end{eqnarray}
\item Résoudre les inéquations suivantes:
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
 2x\le 22 \hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} -5x\le 6
\end{eqnarray}
\item On considère le système suivant: 
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber (E):\left\{
 \begin{array}{lll}
  3x-y=6\\ x+2y=16
 \end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
est ce qu le paire $(5;9)$ est une solution pour $(E)$
\item résoudre $(E)$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,title=exercice 2 ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=cyan}]
Le tableau suivant, donne les quantités d'oranges récoltées dans un champ par le nombre d'ouvriers pendant chaque journée:
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  la quantité d'oranges (Kg) & 100 & 120 & 140 & 160 & 200 \\\hline
  l'effectif (nombre d'ouvriers) & 20 & 30 & 10 & 25 & 15\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\item donner le nombre total des ouvriers recensés. \item quel est le mode de cette série statistique.
Calculer la moyenne arithmétique de cette série statistique.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\newtcolorbox` help? `\newtcolorbox{exercise}{<options>}` defines a new environment `exercise`, where `\begin{exercise}` is equivalent to `\begin{tcolorbox}[<options>]`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thank you a lot of,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@muzimuzhi Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/79060/muzimuzhi-z) pointed out, you can define a new `tcolorbox`:

```
\newtcolorbox{exercisebox}[1]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    title=#1,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={
        size=small,
        colback=cyan
    }
}
```

and use it in your document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newtcolorbox{exercisebox}[1]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    title=#1,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={
        size=small,
        colback=cyan
    }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{exercisebox}{exercise 1}
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item Résoudre les équations suivantes:
   \begin{eqnarray}
    \nonumber 4x=16\hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} (2x-7)(x+9)=0
   \end{eqnarray}
\item Résoudre les inéquations suivantes:
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
 2x\le 22 \hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} -5x\le 6
\end{eqnarray}
\item On considère le système suivant: 
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber (E):\left\{
 \begin{array}{lll}
  3x-y=6\\ x+2y=16
 \end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
est ce qu le paire $(5;9)$ est une solution pour $(E)$
\item résoudre $(E)$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercisebox}
\begin{exercisebox}{exercise 2}
Le tableau suivant, donne les quantités d'oranges récoltées dans un champ par le nombre d'ouvriers pendant chaque journée:
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  la quantité d'oranges (Kg) & 100 & 120 & 140 & 160 & 200 \\\hline
  l'effectif (nombre d'ouvriers) & 20 & 30 & 10 & 25 & 15\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\item donner le nombre total des ouvriers recensés. \item quel est le mode de cette série statistique.
Calculer la moyenne arithmétique de cette série statistique.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercisebox}
  \begin{exercisebox}{exercise 1}
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item Résoudre les équations suivantes:
   \begin{eqnarray}
    \nonumber 4x=16\hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} (2x-7)(x+9)=0
   \end{eqnarray}
\item Résoudre les inéquations suivantes:
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
 2x\le 22 \hspace{0.4cm} ;; \hspace{0.4cm} -5x\le 6
\end{eqnarray}
\item On considère le système suivant: 
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber (E):\left\{
 \begin{array}{lll}
  3x-y=6\\ x+2y=16
 \end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
est ce qu le paire $(5;9)$ est une solution pour $(E)$
\item résoudre $(E)$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercisebox}
\begin{exercisebox}{exercise 2}
Le tableau suivant, donne les quantités d'oranges récoltées dans un champ par le nombre d'ouvriers pendant chaque journée:
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  la quantité d'oranges (Kg) & 100 & 120 & 140 & 160 & 200 \\\hline
  l'effectif (nombre d'ouvriers) & 20 & 30 & 10 & 25 & 15\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\item donner le nombre total des ouvriers recensés. \item quel est le mode de cette série statistique.
Calculer la moyenne arithmétique de cette série statistique.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercisebox}
\end{document}
```